# Sharing a unit test withing multiple projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I have a common db unit test which is used to test naming convetions, it's shared between multiple projects as a an existing file link within visual studio and this runs fine per project ( each project is specific a db).
However it breaks the VS test editor support since the projects with the shared file do not show up in the test view as it shows an error when loading:
Error loading C:\: The test 'DefaultConstraints' from 'c:\listtest.dll' that is loading has the same TestId {3c0c0672-f45b-4b13-697a-77d588b873e4} as the test 'DefaultConstraints' already loaded from 'c:\sandbox\commontest.dll'.

So I can't run the test within VS but can using MSBuild, is there a better way to share common tests?

Comment: Wouldn't common tests imply a common library (or opportunity for such) that could be compiled and tested separately eliminating additional testing effort on your projects which reuse it?

Comment: I guess the purpose is to reuse a test class defined in another project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/574115/unit-tests-error-because-vs-mixes-up-the-debug-and-release-binaries#